# creating html table based on an algorithm suggestion

Tags: php

I'm trying to create an algorithm and want to get your suggestions about that.

There are 4 numbers from 1 to 4 (The sum of this number can vary e.q: 10 or 20).
According to the above total number a html table will occur automatically as below.

[image]

After the formation of the table;

1. Every number will put into the table randomly from **R1** to **R3** just once.
2. Every number necessarily  must be in every rows.
3. If current number was in B side (of colums), next time (i mean, in next row) must be in A side or just the opposite.
4. Every numbers necessarily must match just once in whole table.

Thank you very much for your advice, help and suggust already now.

Comment: It is a bit difficult to figure out what you are looking for. Maybe you could provide a sample of the data and what the table would look like for that data.

Comment: „There are 6 numbers from 1 to 4“ – This doesn't make any sense at all. Did you mean 4 numbers from 1 to 4, representing the different teams in the league? Please don't be unnecessarily abstract if you could be talking about something as simple as sports.

Comment: Sorry, you are right. I edited wrong my post yesterday.

Answer (score 0):

Is this the algorithm to match teams together in tournaments and make sure each team plays against every other team just once?  If so, you may want to look into the [Swiss-system tournament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swiss-system_tournament) or [Round-Robin tournament](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Round-robin_tournament).  It may be very hard to do this in a randomized fashion, it might work better to use a systematic approach.

Comment: Thank you. Yes this is the games fixture of a complete season's first half schedule algoritm.

Comment: Do you know different fixture algoritms other than you suggested.

Comment: „It may be very hard to do this in a randomized fashion, it might work better to use a systematic approach.“ – I agree. If I recall correctly, round-robin will at least be unable to satisfy condition #3, possibly also #2, in most scenarios. (It might be impossible in general.)